# creating a bank customer program

Tags: javascript, oop

I have some requirements for this OOP project. First, here is my code:

```
function Bank (customer, balance, amount, withdraw) {

          this.customer = customer;
          this.balance = balance;
          this.amount = amount;
          this.withdraw = withdraw;

          this.currentCustomers = {
            account: 0

          },

          this.printAccount = function () {
          return `${this.customer}'s new balance is ${this.balance}`;
          },

          this.deposit = function () {
            return `${this.customer}'s new balance is ${balance + this.amount}`;
          },

          

          this.withdraw = function (withdraw) {
            if(this.balance < this.withdraw) {
              throw "Warning! Insufficient funds!";
            } else {
            return `${this.customer}'s new balance is ${balance - withdraw}`;
           }
          }

        }
        

        const newBank = new Bank('Sheldon');
        console.log(newBank.customer);

        const newBank1 = new Bank('Sheldon', 0);
        console.log(newBank1.printAccount());

        const newBank2 = new Bank ('Sheldon', 0, 5);
        console.log(newBank2.deposit());  
 
        const newBank3 = new Bank ('Sheldon', 0, 5);
        console.log(newBank3.withdraw());
```

I need to:

1. be able to add a customer
2. show their bank amount before adding a new amount and after
3. show any deposits and update their account
4. show withdrawals and throw an error message if the withdrawal is less than current amount
5. show all customers and their present account status

Comment: What is the question? :p

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually asked a question here, but I ran your code and I see that you are getting an `NaN` balance on your `withdraw` scenario.

I think you've got some fundamental confusion between what should be an instance variable (a property of Sheldon's Bank) and what should be passed as an argument to a function.  `withdraw()` takes an argument, but there is also a `withdraw` variable that is passed to the constructor.  Why?

Does this class represent an entire bank, or a single user's account?  It is trying to be both, but those need to be two separate classes.

You need to do a lot more learning about OOP design.  But if it helps, I've rewritten your class to how I think it should be.  I'm using the [ES6 class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) rather than the `function` syntax, but that's unrelated to the core issues here.  Behind the scenes they are both functions.  Since you are a beginner, I'll avoid talk about public vs. private variables, but that's something to learn about eventually.

One of the core ideas of what I wrote is that the `balance` of `BankAccount` should change as a result of calling methods like `withdraw` and `deposit`.  In order to create an account, we just need a name and an initial balance.  `withdraw` and `deposit` are independent operations which can be called many times.  They should not depend on constructor arguments.

I thought a bit about how to log everything and how to keep track of how much money has been withdrawn. I think I'm getting too advanced/tricky here, but my ideal solution would be that all transactions should return a receipt containing the current balance and some transactions (withdraw and close account) also return money.  So either `Receipt` or `Transaction` could be another separate class.  But right now I have a whole bunch of `console` statements just for demoing.

```js
class Bank {
    constructor() {
        this.accounts = [];
    }
    // doesn't need a constructor right now since it takes no arguments
    // add a new account for a customer and return the acount
    createAccount(customer, initialBalance = 0) {
        const account = new BankAccount(customer, initialBalance);
        this.accounts.push(account);
        return account;
    }
    // return the account that matches a name, or undefined if none exists
    findAccountByName(customer) {
        return this.accounts.find(account => account.customer === customer);
    }
    // return only accounts with status of 'open'
    getActiveAccounts() {
        return this.accounts.filter(account => account.status === "open");
    }
    // get the names for all customer acounts
    getCustomerNames() {
        return this.accounts.map(account => account.customer);
    }
    // get the sum of all balances in all accounts
    getTotalAssets() {
        return this.accounts.reduce((sum, account) => sum + account.balance, 0);
    }
}

class BankAccount {
    constructor(customer, initialBalance = 0) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.status = 'open';
        this.balance = initialBalance;
        console.log(`created a new account for ${this.customer} with balance ${this.balance}`);
    }
    deposit(amount) {
        console.log(`${this.customer}'s balance went from ${this.balance} to ${this.balance + amount} after depositing ${amount}`);
        this.balance = this.balance + amount;
    }
    withdraw(amount) {
        if (this.balance < amount) {
            console.error("Warning! Insufficient funds!");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            console.log(`${this.customer}'s balance went from ${this.balance} to ${this.balance - amount} after widthdrawing ${amount}`);
            this.balance = this.balance - amount;
            return amount;
        }
    }
    // widthdraw all remaining funds and change account status
    closeAccount() {
        this.withdraw(this.balance); // will log a balance
        this.status = 'closed';
        console.log(`${this.customer}'s account has been closed`);
    }
    checkBalance() {
        console.log(`${this.customer}'s current balance is ${this.balance}`);
    }
}

const bank = new Bank;
const account = bank.createAccount('Sheldon', 0);
account.deposit(5);
account.withdraw(1);
account.deposit(20);
account.withdraw(100);
console.log("bank customers", bank.getCustomerNames());
console.log("bank assets", bank.getTotalAssets());
```

Comment: That was mind-blowing! Kudos for taking the time. Didn't know you could create an instance of a class in another class i.e.  ```const account = new BankAccount(customer, initialBalance); ``` in class Bank.                                                                                                                Have a Q. You created the above const account and then another const account at the end. Obviously it works, but if I were to write: ```const newAccount = bank....  ``` and then store that in another function, before calling it, would it also work? const  is unchanging

Comment: Yes, you can name it anything.  I didn't realize that I used the same variable name, but it's not an issue because they are in separate scopes.  The `const account = new BankAccount(customer, initialBalance);` only exists within the body of the `createAccount` function.  You can't access that variable anywhere else.  That's why we return a value.  You can save the returned value to any variable name.